# Timestamp in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5, angular2-forms

I am working with a project using Angular 5 for DB purposes i am using Firebase. Actually i used firebase:'^4.12.1' before and it work properly for me. Now the theme of project is changed due to which faced many issue and finally i have to change version of firebase all issues resolved but facing Timestamp issue.
Below is my code..

> .html

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="startdate">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header><b>Start Date</b> </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.itemCategoryRows.startdate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="enddate">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header><b>End Date </b> </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.itemCategoryRows.enddate | date:'mediumDate'}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
```

Comment: Can you check in which format are you getting the date, What error is shown in the chrome (Browser) console?

Comment: what is data of `item.itemCategoryRows.startdate`

Comment: @PiniCheyni This is error in console when is click to view detail
Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Timestamp(seconds=1531681200, nanoseconds=0)' for pipe 'DatePipe'
    at invalidPipeArgumentError

Comment: @KrishnaRathore I am using reactive forms itemCategoryRows is an array and items is another for storing data after fetch from firebase startdate is formControlName of filed

Comment: @Naeem I have post answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because there's a breaking change in the Firebase JavaScript SDK where dates are saved on the database and returned as a [`firebase.firestore.Timestamp`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp) object.

In the [`Timestamp`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp) class, there's a [`toDate`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#toDate) method which converts the object to a native JavaScript `Date`.

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="startdate">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header><b>Start Date</b> </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.itemCategoryRows.startdate.toDate() | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="enddate">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header><b>End Date </b> </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.itemCategoryRows.enddate.toDate() | date:'mediumDate'}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `{{item.itemCategoryRows.startdate * 1000 | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}`

and multiply `1000` in timestamp.

I have create a demo on [**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/timestamp-in-angular-5?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts)

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="startdate">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
        <b>Start Date</b>
    </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.itemCategoryRows.startdate * 1000 | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="enddate">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
        <b>End Date </b>
    </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.itemCategoryRows.enddate * 1000 | date:'mediumDate'}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Timestamp error removed from console by using your code but cannot work properly. Date not show in grid.

Comment: I will create demo on Stackblitz

Comment: I have create a demo on `Stackblitz` - https://stackblitz.com/edit/timestamp-in-angular-5?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts